# Can the WSO API Manager proxy a web service that is on the app server and authenticated using the identity server?

Tags: authentication, proxy, wso2

I have several web services that I want to make available to clients. My clients are split into two groups:

- users using a web browser (I serve a web page that uses javascript + AJAX to request data from the web services)
- applications (e.g. server app pulling data into a client's system)

1) I can solve the former by exposing my web services to external users using the application server and I can use the identity server to authenticate access (haven't worked how to do this out yet).

2) The latter is nicely satisfied by using the API manager. I can happily tell clients to log in to the API manager and subscribe to APIs. The APIs I create are proxies for the web services mentioned in 1).

I know that an API I create in the API manager can include a username and password for accessing the proxied web service. Is it possible to let an API proxy a web service that is authenticated using the identity manager? Sorry I'm reading documentation and struggling to understand if I can do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> ". Is it possible to let an API proxy a web service that is
>   authenticated using the identity manager? "

Currently APIManager supports the service endpoints which are secured using basicauth/usernametoken.
If you use identityserver to secure you service, using any other mechanism, that wont be supported by APIManager.

Answer (score 0):

Stodge,

Default API manager authentication mechanism is Oauth. it uses Oauth token mechanism to authenticate all APIs.
Please refer [1],

Here the authentication component also sits in the AM. This can be delegated to a different AM instance if required.

Hope this helps.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Token+APIs